# How do i create my own clasiifier

Tags: c++, opencv

Now I am creating my own classifier for face detection.I have two folder one for storing positive images and other for storing negative images. And I make .txt files for both. Now  I want to create training samples of positive imgaes. So I give command 'opencv_createsamples -info positives.txt -vec myvec.vec -w 24 -h 24 '. But It shows like this.It doesn't create any samples.What is the reason?Could any one help me. Thanks in advance.

```
Info file name: positives.txt 
Img file name: (NULL) 
Vec file name: myvec.vec 
BG  file name: (NULL) 
Num: 1000 
BG color: 0 
BG threshold: 80 
Invert: FALSE 
Max intensity deviation: 40 
Max x angle: 1.1 
Max y angle: 1.1 
Max z angle: 0.5 
Show samples: FALSE 
Width: 24 
Height: 24 
Create training samples from images collection... 
positives.txt(1) : parse errorDone. Created 0 samples
```

Answer (score 0):

The info file should not contain only file names, but also ROI specification.
each line should look like this:

> path/to/image.bmp num_rois x y width height x y width height ...

For example if you have files that are exactly as big as the sample size, each line should be:

> path/to/image.bmp 1 0 0 24 24

note that the path to the image file should be relative to the location of the info file. also the default number of samples is 1000, if you want to include all the samples in your info file you should specify it through the command line.

a good guide can be found on the opencv web site: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html#positive-samples